# Codeigniter - no input file specified

Tags: codeigniter, php

I am a beginner in Codeigniter and I saw a CI tutorial and was just trying to do a simple thing. I downloaded the CI and added this file to controller directory, but it won't work.

```
<?php

class site extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo "Hello World";
    }

    function dosomething()
    {
        echo "Do Something";
    }   
}    
?>
```

When I try to access it using http://..../index.php/site I get the output ... "no input file specified" .... by the way, I named the file site.php

Comment: Try checking out [this link](http://www.terencechang.com/2008/08/28/codeigniter-no-input-file-specified-php-5-apache-2/) and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: No doesnt help thanks for the effort

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I found the answer to this question here..... The problem was hosting server... I thank all who tried .... Hope this will help others

[**Godaddy Installation Tips**](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Godaddy-Installation-Tips)

Comment: change above line according to your application directory
like if you application is not on root directory , write following code in place of above line
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub-directory/index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]`

Answer (score 309):

Just add the **?** sign after index.php in the .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

and it would work !

Comment: For me this serves a 301 redirect and I end up with /?/ in the URL.

Comment: @Ali Mohamed, which of the htaccess file do you add this line? I tried but does not have any effect

Comment: @Bahdeng you need to place this snippet in .htaccess file in your project directory.

Comment: change above line according to your application directory
like if you application is not on root directory , write following code in place of above line
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub-directory/index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: where is the .htaccess? I can't find it

Comment: @NSGodMode that would be in codeigniter root directory besides index.php

Comment: @AliMohamed for some reason mine didn't have one, So I had to create a .htaccess in the root directory

Comment: Worked like a Charm.. . In this programming world One "?" can also change the picture.. .

Answer (score 63):

Godaddy hosting it seems fixed on `.htaccess`, myself it is working

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: change above line according to your application directory
like if you application is not on root directory , write following code in place of above line
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub-directory/index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: Its getting me 404 page not found with CI 3

Answer (score 18):

## RewriteEngine, DirectoryIndex in .htaccess file of CodeIgniter apps

I just changed the **.htaccess** file contents and as shown in the following [links](https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/155801/) answer. And tried refreshing the page (which didn't work, and couldn't find the request to my controller) it worked.

Then just because of my doubt I undone the changes I did to my **.htaccess** inside my **public_html** folder back to original **.htaccess** content. So it's now as follows (which is originally it was):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And now also it works.

**Hint:**  Seems like before the Rewrite Rules haven't been clearly setup within the Server context.

My file structure is as follows:

```
/
|- gheapp
|    |- application
|    L- system
|
|- public_html
|    |- .htaccess
|    L- index.php
```

And in the `index.php` I have set up the following paths to the system and the application:

```
$system_path = '../gheapp/system';
$application_folder = '../gheapp/application';
```

**Note:** by doing so, our application source code becomes hidden to the public at first.

Please, if you guys find anything wrong with my answer, comment and re-correct me!
Hope beginners would find this answer helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My site is hosted on MochaHost, i had a tough time to setup the .htaccess file so that i can remove the index.php from my urls. However, after some googling, i combined the answer on this thread and other answers. My final working .htaccess file has the following contents:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Turn on URL rewriting
    RewriteEngine On

    # If your website begins from a folder e.g localhost/my_project then 
    # you have to change it to: RewriteBase /my_project/
    # If your site begins from the root e.g. example.local/ then
    # let it as it is
    RewriteBase /

    # Protect application and system files from being viewed when the index.php is missing
    RewriteCond $1 ^(application|system|private|logs)

    # Rewrite to index.php/access_denied/URL
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/access_denied/$1 [PT,L]

    # Allow these directories and files to be displayed directly:
    RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|public|app_upload|assets|css|js|images)

    # No rewriting
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [PT,L]

    # Rewrite to index.php/URL
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This solved my problem and got my site working as of October 2021. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One of my Codeigniter apps started returning this error after i restarted my server.
When I checked the Codeigniter error log it says something like:
"...[error] 879#0: *273 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Unknown: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/pathToWebsiteRootFolder/index.php) is not within the allowed path(s): ".
So I added this:
open_basedir= /pathToWebsiteRootFolder/index.php:

To a user.ini file I created in my website root folder.

And this Solved it.

FYI: Im using an NGINX web server.

However, Its strange because I didn't have to do this for the other Apps on the same server.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33178756)