# Codeigniter "No input file specified" even after pasting a new .htacess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am trying to install codeIgniter and I have copied all of codeIgniter files to a folder called `/backend` in `http://www.mydomain.com`.

Now, `http://www.mydomain.com/backend/index.php` shows the codeIgniter welcome page.

Then I created a `main.php` in the `/backend/controller` folder. But when I open `http://www.mydomain.com/backend/index.php/main`, it shows `No input file specified`.

After looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118740/codeigniter-no-input-file-specified), i pasted a .htaccess file with the following contents into the `/backend` folder.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

But the page `http://www.mydomain.com/backend/index.php/main` still says `No input file specified`.

Why is the `.htaccess` not making any difference? I don't understand whats going on.

Comment: It might be the mod_rewrite is not enabled on your server, or that AllowOverrides (i.e. enable .htaccess files) is not turned on.

Comment: With that .htaccess file, you'd probably want your url to be in the form `mydomain.com/backend/main`.  Since it's directing all requests for non-existent files to index.php, there's not point in directly requesting index.php

Comment: @MikeBrant mod_rewrite is enabled and the same .htaccess file carries out other redirects.

Comment: @SamDufel the url `mydomain.com/backend/main` shows a 404.

Comment: @blenderous - try switching either `RewriteBase` to `/backend` or changing the `RewriteRule` to `^(.*)$ backend/index.php?/$1 [L]`

Comment: Post your main.php so we can eliminate the possibility of an error in your class. Do you still have the welcome controller, if so what happens when you go to `mydomain.com/backend/index.php/welcome/index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /backend
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /backend/index.php/$1 [L]
```

then browse to :

```
http://www.mydomain.com/backend/main
```

and not to:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/backend/index.php/main
```

be sure you removed `index.php` in `config/config.php` and you setted `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO'; (try also other solutions here if still not working)`