# Url is not working properly in codeigniter giving error "No input file specified".

Tags: php, codeigniter

I uploaded my codeigniter application to a demo server. The [Home page](http://globalcfos.com/cfoask/) is opening fine, but other pages are giving [error](http://globalcfos.com/cfoask/cfo_rates).

I changed the `base url` in my config file to:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://globalcfos.com/cfoask/';
```

It is working fine locally. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Please ignore this question I got the answer in this link . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118740/codeigniter-no-input-file-specified

Comment: Good stuff! You can post it as an **answer** if you want, *cheers* ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're hosted on GoDaddy, having bumped into the same issue before, changing your .htaccess file to the below should fix it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?/$1
```

See http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/77847/