# home.php not being accessed in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a few sites set up on CI but latest one isn’t cooperating: browsing the domain doesn’t trigger home.php. I get “No input file specified”. I must be missing? (btw, when I put a test index.php file in root the echo code does render)
Here's what I've got set up -

```
//permissions:
//all subdirectories & file set to 755

//config.php:
$config[‘base_url’] = ‘http://example.com’;
$config[‘index_page’] = ‘home’;

//htaccess in root:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

//routes.php:
$route[‘default_controller’] = “home”;
$route[‘404_override’] = ‘’;

//home.php:
class Home extends CI_Controller {
public function index()
 {
  $this->load->library('session');
  $this->load->view('main_view');
  }
}
```

My settings seem to mirror those of my other the working CI sites but I’m definitely missing something. Would appreciate feedback on what else I should look for. Thanks

Comment: Did you [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13061590/423235)?

Comment: Thanks. But didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'default_controller' config must be 'home/index'

Also be sure you placed the default config on the bottom of the file. In the CI routes files, always start from the most specific to the most general ...

Comment: This is where I when wrong. Renamed index.php for testing - didn't rename it back. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're removing `index.php` from your URI, you don't need to specify an `index_page` in `config.php`.  Setting `$config['index_page'] = '';` should solve your problem.  You should be fine leaving your `$route['default_controller']` as it is, since CodeIgniter automatically defaults to the `index` method.