# Using Carbon api for date time codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime, php-carbon

I'm trying to use Carbon API(https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) for my project in Codeigniter. But I am having trouble using it.
I first installed it with composer. But when I use the following code in my project:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Carbon\Carbon;
printf("Now: %s", Carbon::now());
```

I get the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in ...
```

So, I tried installing it manually(Copy and past the Carbon class file to my project). Then it worked fine when I tested the following code:

```
 $now = Carbon::now();
 die($now);
```

But when I try to run something like this:

```
$dtKtm = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $data['banners'][0]['date_added']); 
echo Carbon::now()->diffForHumans($dtKtm, false);
```

> It gives me " Class 'Translator' not found" error.

Can anyone help me fix this.

Comment: Original question was answered.  This is an entirely new question.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, cherrysoft. But I still can't get to use the Carbon API for date/time translation in my project, so modified my question accordingly.

Comment: Would love to help but original question was answered.  Good luck resolving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Carbon Date Time library usage with CodeIgniter

#### CodeIgniter App setup:

First let me give you an introduction about my CodeIgniter project setup on the localhost is as follows:

```
/
|- gheapp
|    |- application
|    |- system
|    L- vendor
|    |     |-bin
|    |     |-composer
|    |     |-nesbot/carbon
|    |     |-symfony
|    |
|    |----- composer.json
|    L----- composer.lock
|
|- public_html
|    |- .htaccess
|    L- index.php
```

And in the `index.php` I have set up the following paths to the system and the application:

```
$system_path = '../gheapp/system';
$application_folder = '../gheapp/application';
```

**Note 1:** by doing so, our application source code becomes hidden to the public at first. 
**Note 2:** For more nitty-gritty about my CodeIgniter setup please follow the following [StackOverflow Answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27074922/1752988)

#### Step 1: how do I fetch the **Carbon** package.

Using Composer I fetched the `Cabron` package to my CodeIgniter App. My `composer.json` looks like following (it's simplified for your ease).

```
{
  "require": {
    "nesbot/carbon": "^1.22"
  }
}
```

After you run composer command `composer install` it creates the `vendor` folder within your CI app root and puts the Carbon package as shown above in the folder structure.

#### Step 2: Autoload Composer downloaded Packages:

In my `index.php` before the line at the bottom

```
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

I have put the following two lines:

```
$composer_vendor_path = '../gheapp/vendor';
require_once $composer_vendor_path.'/autoload.php';
```

So now my `CodeIgniter` app knows how and where to load the composer installed Packages.

#### Step 3: how do I use the **Carbon** package within my controller:

Within any method function of my controller (or model) I can use `Carbon` as follows:

```
    $date = Carbon\Carbon::today();
    echo $date;   // output:  2017-01-21 00:00:00
    echo '<br/>'.$date->diffForHumans();  // output: 7 hours ago
```

For further details about using Carbon please visit the following link: [Carbon from nesBot](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

I hope my answer will be useful/helpful to somebody else out there in the future! :-)

Answer (score 4):

You need to autoload the vendor folder in your bootstrap (In the `index.php` file before the line at the bottom `require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';`).

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

The you need to import the libraries namespace in your model / controller (wherever you are using Carbon).

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

Only then can you use the library.

Comment: I've updated my problem (question). Please have a look at it once again. Any way to fix this?

Comment: If you mark the answer as being correct for the original question as it was the correct answer I can look at, however, you should be asking a new question as this is an entirely different issue.

Answer (score 4):

the easiest way that i found is:

1. install carbon using:

   - `composer require nesbot/carbon`
2. open *application/config/config.php* and change:

   - `$config['composer_autoload'] = FALSE;` or whatever
     to
   - `$config['composer_autoload'] = FCPATH . '/vendor/autoload.php';`
3. call whatever carbon function in your controller:

   - `$data['carbondate'] = Carbon\Carbon::now();`