# codeigniter redirects all my pages to old domains except homepage

Tags: codeigniter

I have a up and running website (eg, abc.com) and i am trying to move the website to new server(eg, problem.com).

I have changed the base_url and also the database but .htaccess is the same.

After the transfer, my homepage is working fine but whenever i click on any page links from menu, its redirected to the page of the old website (for eg, abc.com/about) instead of problem.com/about. When i manually type the link in the browser as problem.com/about i see **"No input file specified."**

**My .htaccess file is as follows:-**

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

**And my config.php file is as follows:-**

$config['base_url'] = 'http://problem.com/';

$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';

$config['url_suffix'] = '';

$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';

$config['proxy_ips'] = '';

My old website is still online and working fine without any errors.

Comment: My best guess: hardcoded href pointing to `abc.com` in nav links (should use `site_url()`). The `no input file` is documented across various resources and a simple google should yield more info on that notice

Comment: e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118740/codeigniter-no-input-file-specified

Comment: though i fixed no input file issues. redirect issue is no fixed. so please donot link my issues with other one

Comment: Did you investigate the first part of my comment? Ci doesn't just magically link to another website. Post the menu code.